# iOS possible for draggable hide button on UITabbar?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Is it possible to add a custom button ontop of a tabbar which can be used to hide and show the tabbar?

I can hide the tabbar but i want to be able to do it from the tabbar itself (button on it)

[image: Mockup of button]

Any ideas?

Comment: You can set Frame of tab bar or use custom tab bar

Comment: @Impossible  
Frame of the tab bar? I'm already using a custom tab bar, but how do i add the button on top of the others like in the picture? iOS is a steep learning curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness (I know you have found this elsewhere), but you can use my "PeekabooTabBarController" for this:

https://github.com/a1phanumeric/PeekabooTabBarController

It allows you to show and hide a UITabBarController, and even allows more buttons which scroll horizontally.

Comment: Its perfect for what i need, when i try to set it as my UITabBarController's tho, it gives this error
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PeekabooTabBarController 0x924d4e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tab.'

Comment: That sounds like the PeekabooTabBarController is connected to an IBOutlet that doesn't exist. Are you using NIBs? If so, open it up and check the last tab on the inspector (the connections panel) for any exclamation marks.